# Python time zone conversion from UTC to EST

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have the below list in python.

```py
[['File_1','2021-09-09 07:05:10'],['File_2','2021-09-08 08:05:11']]
```

The above timestamp is a string in UTC timezone. I would like to convert this to EST timezone.

I tried using pytz package using

```py
datetime.strptime(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

but it gives me result like

```py
['File_1',datetime.datetime(2021,09,03,4,20,5)].
```

The format of date time is not as expected.

Comment: What is your expected output format?

Comment: Same as the input format.but the timezone should change from UTC to EST

Comment: datetime as a data structure has no *format*. If you need a string like '2021-09-08 08:05:11', it's a string representing date/time in a certain format. Side note: if a date/time string has time from a certain time zone, at least the UTC offset should be provided with date and time, otherwise it's pretty easy to be misinterpreted as UTC for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set UTC first, then convert to the desired tz:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+ standard lib

l = [['File_1','2021-09-09 07:05:10'],['File_2','2021-09-08 08:05:11']]

out = [[i[0], datetime.fromisoformat(i[1]) # Python 3.7+
                .replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
                .astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))] for i in l]
       
print(out)
# [['File_1', datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 9, 3, 5, 10, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/New_York'))], ['File_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 4, 5, 11, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/New_York'))]]

# with pytz:
import pytz

outp = [[i[0], datetime.fromisoformat(i[1]) # Python 3.7+
                .replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
                .astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))] for i in l]
print(outp)
# [['File_1', datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 9, 3, 5, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)], ['File_2', datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 4, 5, 11, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)]]
```

If you want a string instead of datetime object, use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) or even simpler: [.isoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).

Comment: Isn't OP asking for the output to be in str like `'2021-09-09 03:05:10'` rather than an object?

Comment: @Luke: that isn't totally clear to me. But it would require to set UTC anyway. Formatting to string is just another method call (strftime)

Comment: Is there a package similar to zoneinfo that is compatible with python 2.7?

Comment: @Padfoot123 for Python 2, you'll have to go with `pytz`. Time zone handling with the Python 3 standard lib (zoneinfo) is still relatively new.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below snippet to get your output in the same format as your input

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from pytz import timezone

timestamp = '2021-09-09 07:05:10'
datetime.strptime(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# Output
'2021-09-09 03:05:10'
```

If you wish to display the timezone in the format, you can use

```
datetime.strptime(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z")

# Output
'2021-09-09 03:05:10 EDT-0400'
```

Comment: `datetime.strptime(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` will give you a naive datetime object which Python treats as local time which is off from UTC most likely - so the conversion with `astimezone` will not give the result one might expect.

Comment: since the question is "conversion from UTC to EST", I think so. Other languages treat datetime without specified time zone as UTC, then it would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to convert it to EST

1st. Declare the list, and identify the date you want to convert as string

```
list = [['File_1','2021-09-09 07:05:10'],['File_2','2021-09-08 08:05:11']]
date_to_convert = list[1][1]
```

2nd. Import the needed libraries

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime,timezone
```

3rd. Convert the string to date time

```
d = datetime.fromisoformat(date_to_convert)
```

4th. Declare datetime timezone as utc.

```
d = date_to_string.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(d.isoformat())
# the output for the above: '2021-09-08T08:05:11+00:00'
```

5th. Set the format and convert to EST

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
est_date = d.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')).strftime(fmt)
print(est_date)
# the output for the above: '2021-09-08 04:05:11'
```

Answer (score -1):

USE THIS WAY REMBER UPERCASE AND LOWERCASE ALSO MATTER

```
import time

timer = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d -- %H:%M:%S %p")
print(timer)
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking for - it just prints the current local time.